# Finding JAXB generated class for root element

Tags: jaxb, document-root

I am new to using JAXB. I need to generate an xml file from its schema, where the schema and element values are input from the user.
My problem is, if I don't know the name of the elements beforehand, how can I use the JAXB generated classes? Is there a generic function, like getRoot() or getChildren() which I can use to traverse through the classes?